# wordpressのサブページが独自ドメインで表示されない

Tags: wordpress, さくらインターネット

さくらインターネットを使って初期ドメインを取得、wordpressでウェブページを作成し公開しました。初期ドメインの他に転入した独自ドメインで同じウェブサイトを表示したいと考えています。

[WordPressの公開URLを変更したい](https://help.sakura.ad.jp/rs/2792/)を参考にして、仮に

```
初期ドメイン：https://example.sakura.ne.jp/wp-test
独自ドメイン：https://example.com
```

とさせていただきます。

現在、初期ドメイン・独自ドメインで同じホーム画面が表示されています。しかし、独自ドメイン上でサブページ「About」をクリック・表示すると

```
https://example.sakura..ne.jp/wp-test/about
```

に飛んでしまいます。これを

```
https://example.com/about
```

となるようにしたいのですが、どのようにすればよいか教えていただけないでしょうか？
どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 参照しているページの「STEP 03」以降は実施されていますか？ WordPress の設定として "公開URL" の項目があるようです。

Comment: 早速ありがとうございます。STEP 03を前回やったときにはなぜかうまく行かなかったのですが、もう一度挑戦したら今度は上手くいきました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決したようでなによりです。コメント欄で終わらせず、ぜひ個別の回答として投稿してもらうと、似た問題で困った人の助けになると思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。たったいま、STEP 03をやり直すとうまく行ったことを回答として投稿しました。

Answer (score 1):

コメント頂いた通り、

[WordPressの公開URLを変更したい](https://help.sakura.ad.jp/rs/2792/?gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiA4Y-sBhC6ARIsAGXF1g6bGZbLW5BYaAnS-NoA-leSy39mcb62DKypVoYDiQ2QzHFa_OHeYXYaAvpCEALw_wcB)

のSTEP 03をやり直すと上手くいきました。コメント頂きましてありがとうございます。